# Every shared user (edit rights) can take over the web app within a Google domain

Tags: google-apps-script

It seems that a user with whom the apps script is shared can deploy a web app. The web app url stays the same as it was when executed by the original account, but now is executed from this user's account. You don't have to be owner of the script within a Google Domain. Is there a way to protect this?
That means:

- edit rights in the spreadsheet & attached apps script code
- not being able to deploy a web app (only the owner will be able)

Comment: What are the settings for who has access to the web app in this case?

Comment: Access to: All users within the domain

Comment: I don't think there's any way to do this within the normal Apps Script settings.  As you say, edit rights in spreadsheet implies edit rights to code implies ability to re-deploy (or even turn off a deployment). Have you investigated attaching the script to a Google Cloud Platform project, and then fine-tuning the IAM settings in the GCP?  Those IAM permissions tend to be more granular--but I don't know offhand if there's a separate one for deployment vs. code editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not currently possible to do this, as anyone with edit access to a Spreadsheet also has edit access to any script that is bound to it. Changing the web app view permissions to 'only me' does stop this from happening, but only because re-publishing as a second user completely breaks the web app in the first place.

#### Feature Request:

You can however let Google know that this is a feature that is important for access to their APIs, and that you would like to request they implement it.

Google's [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com) is a place for developers to report issues and make feature requests for their development services, I'd urge you to make a feature request there. The best component to file this under would be the [Google  Apps Script component](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191640&template=824113), with the `Feature Request` template.

Comment: Great stuff, this was helpful to me!